# How to compress JSON file in the appropriate size?

Tags: json

I am making a webpage by taking the JSON data and using it to plot the boundaries but it is taking to much time to load as the file size is approx 22 MB. Actually It is an Indian Map JSON file. I have two files to plot the JSON data but one does not contain updated boundaries of the country and another one is too large.

Do you suggest some source to compress it or suggest some other file of appropriate size?

Comment: what is the max size you expect to get in the process?

Comment: if you compress the json, you will reduce the download time, not the rendering time since the client must decompress in any case to read and parse the data. I would change the file format to stream the data (stream doesn't require to read all the file in memory)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski another file which does not contain updated boundaries is of 168 KB. So I expect it should be max of 1 MB.

Answer (score 8):

## Serialization

If the size of the outcome does not have to be that small, you can consider different serialization methods. Since JSON is human readable language it also isn't the most space-efficient format.

For example, representing the number 1234.567890123457 will take 18 bytes in UTF-8 stringified JSON. However, a binary format could represent the same number as a 8-byte floating point double. Similarly false will be 5-bytes in JSON, but a single byte (or conceivably less) in a binary format. Depending on the structure of the data it may be better to use a binary serialization techniques.

Some of the serializators you could try would be

- CBOR
- Smile
- BSON
- MessagePack
- Ion (Both Textual and Binary formats)

It would require further testing, but you should be able to decrease the size easily by half with some of the methods

## Compression

If you want to compress it anyway, please take into account that compressing the serialized data most of the time will negate any advantages of using binary format of data serialization, final compressed size has very little to do with the serialization method, and almost eveything to do with the compression method. Choosing the best compression algorithm is a balancing game between the cost to store the data and the cost to compress the data, but you can choose the right balance according to your expected lifecycle and read patterns.

Personally I've used gzip because it is fast, gets effective results, and works natively in the JVM. However, you can choose Brotli, I've heard it provides great results in compressing static front-end javascript assets. You can also try XZ, Zstandard, and bzip2.

As a result of compression you may be able to reduce data size tenfold, however 2MB download everytime client loads a page may still be too high

### Compression example

For instance using brotli on the data you've provided I've managed to reduce the size of the data to 3.4MB. I'm sure some different combination of compression method and serialization could lead to a smaller data file, but then again, it may negatively affect the compression/decompression speed. Using compression in nodejs with a code provided below:

```
const brotli = require('brotli');
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const compressed = brotli.compress(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "india.json")), {
    mode: 0, // 0 = generic, 1 = text, 2 = font (WOFF2)
    quality: 11, // 0 - 11
    lgwin: 22 // window size
});
```

Took me about 2 minutes to fully compress, however since it can be precompressed it shouldn't matter as much, what truly matters though is the speed of decompression on the client side, which takes under one second in the same environment the compression took place.

```
const data = brotli.decompress(fs.readFileSync("compressed.bin"));
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/decoded.json", data);
```

Comment: here I am sharing the link of that JSON file     https://github.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/blob/master/India.json